# How to have a pom.xml but prevent Maven being used for building?

Tags: maven-3

I have a project for which I have created a pom.xml. However, I'm not using Maven as my build system, I am using something else (e.g. ANT). But I want the pom.xml to exist for the use of other tools, e.g. IDEs. How can I make sure, that if someone downloads my project and tries to build it with Maven, they will get a clear indication that they are doing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to pom.xml:

```
   <properties>
      <maven.build.not.supported>
         Do not use Maven to build this module. Please see README.html for
         instructions on how to build it.
      </maven.build.not.supported>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>fail-clean-lifecycle</id>
                  <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                  <configuration>
                     <tasks>
                        <fail message="${maven.build.not.supported}" />
                     </tasks>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>fail-default-lifecycle</id>
                  <phase>validate</phase>
                  <configuration>
                     <tasks>
                        <fail message="${maven.build.not.supported}" />
                     </tasks>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>fail-site-lifecycle</id>
                  <phase>pre-site</phase>
                  <configuration>
                     <tasks>
                        <fail message="${maven.build.not.supported}" />
                     </tasks>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

Since we cannot apparently bind a plugin execution to multiple phases, we need to repeat the execution block three times, one for each of the built-in lifecycles (clean, default and site). To avoid duplication of the failure message, we store it in a Maven property and reuse that property in each execution. In each execution we bind to the first phase of the lifecycle to fail it immediately.